# A Bug in Jodatime calculating Period between 2 date range (which is ALMOST a year)

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I just started to use Joda Time and for a week now I was satisfied with the results. I am trying to get the time range period between two dates of the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH'.

Until I came to a test case I am writing and it seems to me the result is wrong:

**2014-02-05 05 - 2016-02-04 05**

**Joda Results:**

`Years: 1  Months: 11  Days: 2  Hours: 0`

**Expected Results:**

`Years: 1  Months: 11  Days: 30  Hours: 0`

I only need 1 more day to get it to a FULL 2 years....

I am not a QA but certainly this is a bug to me... I also talked to our QA about this and she agreed.

I want to raise a bug in Github but it pointed me to use Stackoverflow first.. any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

```
String hourFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH";
String startTime = "2014-02-05 05";
String endTime   = "2016-02-04 05";
DateTimeFormatter hourFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(hourFormat);
DateTime start = hourFormatter.parseDateTime(startTime);
DateTime end   = hourFormatter.parseDateTime(endTime  );
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
System.out.println(String.format(
  "Years: %d  Months: %d  Days: %d  Hours: %d",
  period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays(), period.getHours()
));
```

Comment: Please add a complete code sample

Comment: To solve my issue, I need to get the Exact Date after the 11th Month and calculate the Days Between that date and the End Date.

**DateTime daysStartTime = endTime.plusHours(1);**


**int days = Days.daysBetween(daysStartTime, end).getDays();**

Comment: To clarify - your code sample that demonstrates he problem is incomplete. Please make it a self-contained compilable example.

Comment: @Krease 

Modified.

Comment: @Krease 
My issue is the computation of the Period using JodaTime. My code comment is my own workaround. But still the issue exists and needs to be resolved.

Comment: I found this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367759/incorrect-jodatime-period-years-months-days

Comment: Main reason for difficulties: The Joda-Time-API uses implicit defaults. And in this case, the expectations what is the right default setting differ between API-designers and (most) API-users, i.e. should weeks be a part of default period calculation or not. I don't like implicit defaults and have therefore developed another alternative ([Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.html#in-U...-)) where users must specifiy how they want the duration to be calculated (that is which units to be used). This is a little bit more writing effort but serves for clarity and readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem like a bug to me. Definitely, as `Interval` actually stores the begin and end dates internally, it should be able to make a proper conversion to a Period (`interval.toPeriod()`).

I bet when you simply calculate the `Period` directly from the two dates (without the intermediate step to an `Interval`), it will work just fine. Example:

```
Period period = new Period(start,end);
```

Or if the calculation is not correct with differences in week, you might need to use (as per [Incorrect jodatime period - years months days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20368493/744133)):

```
Period period = new Period(start,end,PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

In the case of Java 8 `java.time.*` libraries (JSR-310), Interval was actually omitted, and only `Period` and `Duration` are allowed. So in Java 8, you could do something like this:

```
String hourFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH";
DateTimeFormatter hourFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(hourFormat);
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("2014-02-05 05",hourFormatter);
LocalDateTime end   = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-02-04 05",hourFormatter);

// Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
Period period = Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate());

System.out.println(
  String.format("Years: %d  Months: %d  Days: %d  Hours: xxx",
  period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays())
);
```

Other obvious limitation is that `Period` in JSR-310 only has a resolution up-to days (not hours).

See also this for further reference: [Is there a class in java.time comparable to the Joda-Time Interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22150722/744133)

Comment: yeah I do understand that it was not a bug :)  since i just started using Joda Time due to my limitation of not using JDK 8.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following lines of code

```
Interval interval =   new Interval(start, end);
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
```

To

```
Period period = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

Comment: Nice job solving the problem :) And welcome to StackOverflow!